# handle key combination when an action is already registered for it

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-gef

My use case would be to handle the <kbd>Ctrl (Cmd) + A</kbd> key combination in a `TextCellEditor`s `Text` control which opens on an "editable" label using gef (language is scala, sorry about that):

```
text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter {
  override def keyPressed(e: KeyEvent) = {
    val ctrlKey = if (Util.isMac) SWT.COMMAND else SWT.CTRL
    if (e.stateMask == ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'a') {
      text.selectAll()
      e.doit = false
    }
  }
})
```

But since a "global" action is registered for the whole gef `GraphicalEditor`, I don't even receive the event.

How could I get around this and make the handler receive the key event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, not sure if it's the most elegant solution, but certainly works (in the cell editor):

```
var originalEnabled: Boolean = true

def globalSelectAllAction = Option(
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench
    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow
    .getActivePage
    .getActiveEditor
    .getEditorSite
    .getActionBars
    .getGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.SELECT_ALL.getId)
)

override def activate() {
  super.activate()
  originalEnabled = globalSelectAllAction.map(_.isEnabled).getOrElse(true)
  globalSelectAllAction.foreach(_.setEnabled(false))
}

override def deactivate() {
  super.deactivate()
  globalSelectAllAction.foreach(_.setEnabled(originalEnabled))
}
```

This temporarily disables the CMD (Ctrl) + A action while the cell editor is active and re-enables it once the editor is gone